# MSSQL connection fails at the second or next attempts

Tags: php, sql-server

Im have a Datatable working with server-side processing. In the first call it works perfectly but connection fails in next attempts. At beginning I thought that was an error on the JSON returned but my PHP log return the next:

> AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning: mssql_select_db(): 15 is not a valid MS SQL-Link resource

And the console log:

> Can't use db : Changed language setting to us_english.

My connection.php is:

```
$conn = mssql_connect($server,$username,$password);
if (!$conn) {  die('Not connected : ' . mssql_get_last_message());} 
$db_selected = mssql_select_db($database, $conn);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mssql_get_last_message());
}
```

I don't know what am I missing, I printed $conn and it was a valid resource,

why is mssql_select_db() failing if it has same parameters?

**[EDIT]**

For those who ask why I make two connections. The database is called from the file that fills the datatable, if a user wants to see page 2 of the table the script is called again to obtain the new data and that is why another connection is made again.

Javascript file:

```
$('#tbl').DataTable( {
        "ajax": {
            "url": "inc/clients.json.php"
        },
    "scrollX": true,
    "serverSide": true,
```

Clients.json.php

```
    include('connection.php');
 //At the end of the file
// SQL operations that works fine  
    mssql_close($conn);
```

That's why two requests are made.

I added to the error message in connection.php

```
Resource conn: ' .get_resource_type($conn)
```

And when the connection fails it shows that $conn is type Unknown, so it looks that the problem is with mssql_connect(), fails with the same parameters

Comment: Why are you connecting twice during one request? Did you close the old connection before opening a new one?

Comment: @bassxzero cause another request its done when the datatable is reorder or when the user want to see page 2. I close the connection at the end of script with    mssql_close($conn);

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: @ChrisSum I changed to PDO sqlsrv driver and all are working fine